Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'. error white dexing
ERROR:D:\l_store\build\url_launcher_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_dir\debug\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity$1.class: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform debug (project :url_launcher_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.libraryelements=classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: D:\l_store\build\url_launcher_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_dir\debug.
> Error while dexing.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I am trying to include Url_laucher package in project and getting this error trying alot searching online but not getting the solution

I think you are using java latest jdk version. You should use flutter compitable version to resolve this error. You can check details via this below url:

https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol/issues/1990#issuecomment-1869279649
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/142420#issuecomment-1915861060


Can you please guide me how which one is the compatible version and how i can update flutter compatible version
